# ext sd card is not working at all and not appearing

Tags: samsung

all other sd cards are working but my card is not showing....neither on mobile or laptop.what to do my all data is in the card.the data card being inserted in my GT-S7562 mobile phone and laptop is not being recognized and neither the data

Answer (score 0):

The SD card may be damaged. If not, try to mount the SD card, because it may be unmounted by the system itself. To do this, go to Settings, to Storage, navigate to the bottom, and then press Mount SD Card.